# Exact differences in c++11 support when using libc++ versus libstc++ on Apple llvm 4.1?

Tags: c++, c++11, xcode4.5, llvm-clang, llvm-c++-api

Can anyone suggest a way to determine the differences in c++11 support when using libc++ versus libstdc++ that ship with the Apple LLVM compiler?

In particular, I am currently using LLVM 4.1 that ships with Xcode 4.5.2.

Presumably, the answer depends in part on the level of c++11 support offered by clang for this version, and in part on the version of libc++ and libstdc++ were shipped with 4.1.

My general sense is that c++11 support is "nearly complete" these days when using libc++, but that you lose something when switching to libstdc++, but i can't figure out what -- a few simple c++11 features seem to work fine on both.

I get the sense that the c++11 support for the libstdc++ that ships with gcc 4.8 is pretty good, but I have no idea if the libstdc++ that ships with llvm 4.1 is old or not.

Also, I get the sense that there is no difference in the level of c++11 support (using llvm 4.1 with libc++) when compiling for osx or ios 6.01, but I'm not positive.

Any suggestions on how to figure all this out?

[Context: due to upstream dependencies,I might need to link to libstdc++ instead of libc++, so I want to figure out what I might be losing]

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, Apple does not use any GPLv3-licensed GCC releases, including the libstdc++ bits. If that's correct, and I'm not entirely sure it is, you're looking at GCC 4.2's libstdc++, and it would surprise me if that includes *any* C++11 support. Given that you say simple C++11 features work fine on both, I may very well have been informed wrong (I don't have a Mac myself), but could you nevertheless include some details on the tests you've run, just to make sure they're tests of the library features? Also, Apple has modified libstdc++, so it may support more than GCC's own.

Comment: I did a ranged-based for loop over a std::vector, but now I'm guessing that doesn't actually use a library feature, but get's away with some sort of syntactic sugar magic.  Unfortunately I'm revisiting c++ after 15 years and my kung fu is a little rusty, and I'm not entirely sure what's a simple one liner that tests library versus language features.  In any case, your explanation, particularly the info about Apple's stance on GPL versions, makes perfect sense and gives me a rational framework from which to refine my understanding.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The libstdc++ that ships with LLVM 4.1 is gcc-4.2.  That version has no C++11 support.  It does have some tr1 support though.

Additionally, the best way to check for C++11 *language* features is to use clang's `has_feature` [macro test](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#cxx11).

For C++11 library features, you'll need to go with libc++.

Comment: Thanks for the info, it's great!  Between your info and @hvd's comment above I think I've a got a reasonable handle on this.  I'm going to mark this answered, by I'm still wondering if there is any difference in c++11 support (either language or library) when compiling for IOS/arm or OSX/intel -- it seems unlikely, but in prior releases there have been differences in Objective-C extensions  support (e.g. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_4.html).  Should I open a new question about this?

Comment: No, there should be no significant difference.  The same tool set is targeting both platforms in each release.